# why is CXF is stripping .json file extension?

Tags: json, rest, service, cxf

My rest service call specifies a path with a json file at the end including the json extension (.json). CXF seems to be stripping out the file extension and causing me trouble. Does anyone know if CXF is filtering on file extensions?

Answer (score 0):

> "Does anyone know if CXF is filtering on file extensions?"

**If you're using JAX-RS** (it seems CXF has support for REST through [JAX-WS Provider and Dispatch](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/rest-with-jax-ws-provider-and-dispatch.html) - you haven't clearly stated which one you're using)**:**

<sup>**Disclaimer:** I was not able to reproduce this with Jersey or Resteasy (JAX-RS 2.0 supported). I am not a CXF user, so I wasn't able to test with CFX</sup>

I read somewhere, that though not in the final spec, some implementers support a part of a draft spec that has this behavior.

This was part of the spec prior to it's final 1.0 release. You can see the last draft where this was part of the spec, [**here**](https://jsr311.java.net/drafts/spec20080627.pdf), in **3.7.1 Request Preprocessing**

> 2. Set
>
>    - `M` = `{config.getMediaTypeMappings().keySet()}`
>    - `L` = `{config.getLanguageMappings().keySet()}`
>    - `m` = `null`
>    - `l` = `null`
>    - Where config is an instance of the application-supplied subclass of ApplicationConfig.
> 3. For each extension (a `.` character followed by one or more alphanumeric characters) `e` in the final path segment scanning from right to left:
>
>    - (a)  Remove the leading ‘.’ character from `e`
>    - (b) If `m` is `null` and `e` is a member of `M` then remove the corresponding extension from the effective request URI and set `m = e`.
>    - (c) Else if `l` is `null` and `e` is a member of `L` then remove the corresponding extension from the effective request URI and set `l = e`. Else go to step 4
> 4. If m is not null then set the value of the Accept header to `config.getExtensionMappings().get(m)`

3(b) is basically saying that the extension should be removed from the requested URI and 4 is stating that there should be some extension mapping that would map say `json` (the extension) to `application/json` and set that as the `Accept` header.

Not sure if this is your problem, but just throwing an idea out there of something you can dig into :-)